# Permanent rooms in BigBlueButton

Tags: java, bigbluebutton

Is there a way to create **PERMANENT ROOMS** in BigBlueButton? If so, any hints? What I am trying to do is to have permanent session where users can join at any moment.

Thank you very much

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do w/ Adobe Flex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see how to create a permanent room, check out the source to demo1.jsp, one of the API examples included in the BigBlueButton distribution.  You can find it in

```
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/demo/demo1.jsp
```

This is the code that is run to login into the Demo Meeting, which you can see here: http://demo.bigbluebutton.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed bigbluebutton demo,
landing page(demo1.jsp) "Demo meeting" is kind of similar thing

http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/install/install.html#6-install-api-demos

Similarly if you wants to have different PERMANENT ROOMS for different users you can generate and maintain unique meeting id (e.g guid) and create meeting with same id every time  user request for the conference.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the sessions /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/demo/demo1.jsp

But i suggest you to customize wordpress. to manage everything for bigbluebutton.

very easily you can integrate the **wordpress** for controll the bigbluebutton sessions(rooms,password,access right,guest account) ,video play back , user based authentication, you can create the conference sessions,you can keep them wait until the presenter login to the room.